# Licensing for SSRS/SQL Server for making SSRS Reports available to public non AD users through ASP.NET Website

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have my public ASP.NET Website which have components to render few SSRS reports. My website does not have any authentication on it and its general public comes to it to see certain reports. The reports are rendered from our internal SSRS Server and displayed on my ASP.NET Website using Report Viewer control. I use an intermediate AD account to talk with SSRS to render reports on my ASP.NET website. Is there any licensing issue to use a single account to render SSRS reports to many end users ? My code works well and its rendering reports as expected, my only concern is with licensing for SQL Server. Is it legal to use this type of integration.  Please let me know.

This is the MSFT article I followed to create this solution. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/using-the-webforms-reportviewer-control?view=sql-server-2017

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer rvControl=new 
ReportViewer();

                rvControl.Height = Unit.Pixel(900);
                rvControl.ProcessingMode = 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
                rvControl.ShowPrintButton = true;

                rvControl.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new 
CustomReportCredentials("userAD", "password", "ADDomain");
                rvControl.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new 
Uri("https://ssrsreportserverUrl/ReportServer"); // Add the Reporting 
Server URL  

                rvControl.ServerReport.ReportPath = "reportpath";
                rvControl.ServerReport.Refresh();
               }
                catch (Exception ex)
              {
throw ex;
               }
           }
```

Comment: Licensing questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow.  But the SQL Server Licensing Guide covers the requirements deploying internet or extranet workloads.  https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/8/C/78CDF005-97C1-4129-926B-CE4A6FE92CF5/SQL_Server_2017_Licensing_guide.pdf

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft , Basically my question is not actually related to Licensing. I would like to know whether we need to do any extra "licensing precautions" to make SSRS reports rendering on an ASP.NET Website through MSFT prescribed Report Viewer Control.

Comment: Per the Licensing guide that's a scenario that requires the SSRS server and SQL Server database server to be licensed under the per-core model.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thank you very much